# jquery check field with confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my snippet jquery code. Pratically i would check if field are empty on submit form, then if the username exist show confirm dialog.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){ 

    $("#form").submit(function(){
        var isFormValid = true;
        if ($.trim($("#telephone").val()).length == 0){
            isFormValid = false;
        alert("Empty telephone!");
        }
    elseif(check_field() == 1){
            if(confirm('Delete?')){
        isFormValid = true;
    }else{
        isFormValid = false;
    }
        return isFormValid;
}); 

function check_field(){  
    var field = $('#field').val();  
    $.post("check_field.php", { field: field }, function(result){ 
        //if the result is 1  
        if(result == 1){  
            return 1;  
        }else{   
            return 0;  

        }  
    });
} 

 }); 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A classic mistake, you need to make a callback in the ajax function because when the function has been executed, the ajax post has not yet been made:

```
function check_field(callback){  
    var field = $('#field').val();  
    $.post("check_field.php", { field: field }, function(result){ 
        //if the result is true
        callback(result == 1);
    });
}
```

And then something like:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault() // prevent the form from submitting... yet
    var $form = $(this);
    check_field(function(result) {
        if(result && confirm('Delete?')) { 
            $form.submit(); // now submit it
         }
    });
});
```

Welcome to the world of asynchronous programming!

Comment: Thk for explanation. I try with your code but received this error: TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: See my addition, you need to bring a function as argument into `check_field`.

Comment: thk, now work. But now i must add a control for check field empty. please show my code.

Comment: You can add more checks before triggering submit. And please don’t update your question with more questions, if you have other questions you can post a new topic instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$.post` call is asynchronous - so the inner return statements don't actually return from inside the `check_field` function at all. The inner function is called once the server has responded.

Essentially, the original `check_field` function issues the POST request, then continues right on without waiting for the server to respond, returning the control flow to the original submit handler.

What you need to do instead, is wait for the async response from the POST, then trigger the submit if the returned validation succeeded.

A very simply implementation could look something like this:

```
jQuery(function(){ 

    $("#form").on('submit', function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this),
            field = $('#field').val();

        $.post("check_field.php", { field: field }, function(result){
            if (result==1 && confirm('Delete?'))
                $form.off().submit();
        });
    });
});
```

**Note**: I updated the code - it is now triggered on the `submit` event, so it will work for both clicking the submit button and using the `enter`key.

Comment: What about submitting via the keyboard? I think it’s better to bind the form submit event instead of a click.

Comment: @David: Sure, but then you need to make sure you don't end up triggering the submit handler again :) I'll change the example though

Answer (score 0):

You should care about the datatypes. 1 is not equal to "1" or '1'. Is it?! Use `"typeof"` to find out the datatype of values. Also just by returning value you can not continue the process. It's a asynchronous call. You should read about that.

Cheers

Comment: He could also just use the triple-equals operator to avoid type coercion.